# ggplot: adding a legend entry for a line to a grouped bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot, in R and using `ggplot2`, a bar chart displaying, for several groups, two variables as bars and one variable as a line. All variables are on the same scale.

Using `diamonds` as an example,

```
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>% 
    group_by(cut) %>% 
    summarize(avg = median(carat), min = min(carat), max = max(carat)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = c("min", "max"), names_to = "bounds", values_to = "weight") %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = weight, fill = bounds), position = "dodge") +
    geom_line(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = avg), group = 1)
```

gives

[image]

What I'd now like to do is two-fold:

1. add a legend entry for the line; and
2. ideally also control the color for the line.

I've searched both google and SO, as well as looked at `scale_color_*`, but without success, and I'm still not really "grokking" `ggplot2`'s idiosyncratic approach to plotting, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `color` to the aesthetic to get a legend for the line and use `scale_color_manual` to change the color line like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  summarize(avg = median(carat), min = min(carat), max = max(carat)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("min", "max"), names_to = "bounds", values_to = "weight") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = weight, fill = bounds), position = "dodge") +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = avg, color = "name_line"), group = 1) +
  scale_color_manual("Legend line", values = c("name_line" = "yellow"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Sometimes, the answer is so simple you don't see the forest for the trees. Thank you.